# PHP class name collision with ctags

Tags: tags, ctags, filetype-php

I have the following php file:

```php
namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;  // #1

class MyValidator // ...
{
    public function validate(Constraint /* #2 */ $constraint): void
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have generated all tags with *exuberant ctags (v5.9)* using the command `ctags -R .`.

Whenever I put my vim cursor on either `#1` or `#2` and try to navigate to the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint` class using `tselect` (actual key pressed: `C-]`), the current buffer is loaded with the `PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint` class instead of `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint`.

Is this a ctags issue or a vim issue ?
What should I do to generate tags that understand php namespace ?

Comment: You might try universal-ctags, and/or the `--extras` option, and/or http://ctags.sourceforge.net/faq.html#7

Answer (score 3):

`<C-]>` is equivalent to `:tag <keyword>`, **not** to `:tselect <keyword>`, the normal mode equivalent of which would be `g]`.

The end result of `$ ctags -R .` is a `tags` file that contains a list of tags found under the working directory. `:tag` and `:tselect` work differently:

- `:tag <keyword>` (and thus `<C-]>`) jumps to the first matching tag found in that `tags` file,
- `:tselect <keyword>` (and thus `g]`) displays a list of the matching tags found in that `tags` file.

In your case, `<C-]>` jumps to the first `Constraint` that was found by `ctags`, which is the expected behavior.

If you use `g]`, you should get a list of potential tags and thus be able to jump to the appropriate one.

That is, of course, if your `tags` file includes what you are looking for.

I recommend `:tjump <keyword>` (and thus `g<C-]>`) instead of either, because it combines the advantages of both:

- if there is only one matching tag, jump to it like `:tag <keyword>`,
- if there are more than one, display a list like `:tselect <keyword>`.

See `:help :tselect`, `:help :tjump`, and `:help :tag`.

Comment: illuminating answer; thank you